# Rails: will_paginate run extra SQL query when calling page_entries_info

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, will-paginate

My application using rails '3.2.20', mysql2 '0.3.20' and will_paginate '3.0.7'

I'm trying to load user records

```
@users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Below queries executed in console

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
```

Generally will_paginate run two queries for collections and count

But I got one more extra query when used page_entries_info in view

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` 
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

hope last query is not used anywhere.

I just illustrate with simple example, but my application executes large query with more joins and includes.

It may slow down the performance with unnecessary query.

This occurs only after will_paginate '3.0.3'

is it bug/functionality? how to avoid this extra query?

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent will_paginate from generating its own query for a count, use the total_entries parameter:

```
@users = User.all
entries = @users.size
@users.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20, :total_entries => entries)
```

Answer (score 0):

`will_paginate` is making extra queries because of lazy execution of queries by rails. Following is implementation of [the method](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/2f0b4694b3cc7ffcb265daad13eb95c972fa0bb1/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers.rb#L105):

```
def page_entries_info(collection, options = {})
  model = options[:model]
  model = collection.first.class unless model or collection.empty? # <= this line
  ...
end
```

If `collection` has not been loaded before that line is executed, rails makes extra queries for `collection.first` and `collection.empty?`. Solution is that you pass the model so that will_paginate does not have to evaluate it:

```
page_entries_info @users, model: 'user'
```